# RegExp: How do I include 'avoid non-numeric characters' from a pattern search?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to filter out all `.+[0-9].` (correct way?) patterns to avoid duplicate decimal points within a numeral: (*e.g.*, `.12345.`); but allow non-numerals to include duplicate decimal points: (*e.g.* `.12345*.`) where `*` is any `NON-NUMERAL`.

How do I include a non-numeral negation value into the regexp pattern? Again,

```
.12345. <-- error: erroneous numeral.<br/>
.12345(.' or '.12345*.' <-- Good.
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift...

Comment: What are you trying to _match_ exactly ? _Bad_, _good_ or non-decimal numerals, or just decimal's ?

Comment: I'm working with equations within a string; from which I parse that string to process the equation.   Hence, it's possible to enter '.12345.' which is erroneous vs '.1234*.' with is viable as in: '.200*.50' (= 0.10).

Comment: The reason I asked what you're trying to match is a really simple `\.\d+\.` is all you need to pick out errors.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I'm looking for.   I really need to master regexp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
^\d*(?:\.\d+)?(?:(?<=\d)[^.\d\n]+\.)?$
```

Here is [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ5yK0/3)

Remember to escape the regex properly in Swift:

```
let rx = "^\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:(?<=\\d)[^.\\d\\n]+\\.)?$"
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - Start of string
- `\d*` - Match a digit optionally
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - Match decimal part, 0 or 1 time (due to `?`)
- `(?:(?<=\d)[^.\d\n]+\.)?` - Optionally (due to `?` at the end) matches 1 or more symbols preceded with a digit (due to `(?<=\d)` lookbehind) other than a  digit (`[^\d]`), a full stop (`[^.]`) or a linebreak (`[^\n]`) (this one is more for demo purposes) and then followed by a full stop (`\.`).
- `$` - End of string

I am using non-capturing groups `(?:...)` for better performance and usability.

**UPDATE**:

If you prefer an opposite approach, that is, *matching the invalid strings*, you can use a much simpler regex:

```
\.[0-9]+\.
```

In Swift, `let rx = "\\.[0-9]+\\."`. It matches any substrings starting with a dot, then 1 or more digits from 0 to 9 range, and then again a dot.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ5yK0/4)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll study it.   BTW: \.\d+\. appears to be the best solution in this case; per son's comment above.

Comment: `\.\d+\.` is the opposite of what I suggest. It matches the text you do not want to be valid. I focused on the regex to match *valid* entries (as individual strings). I added my version of the approach.

Comment: So, did you have time to check? Please come back when you find out what is working for you, and mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The non-numeral regex delimited character is `\D`. Conversely, if you're looking for only numerals, `\d` would work.

Without further context of what you're trying to achieve it's hard to suggest how to build a regex for it, though based on your example, (I think) this should work: `.+\d+\D+`